# How do I use an image in an asp.net Menu?

Tags: asp.net, menu

I'm using an asp.net Menu (asp:Menu - the built-in one) and I want to assign an image to each MenuItem at design time, but the menu never changes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The menu items have an [ImageUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.imageurl.aspx) property that you can set to the URL of the image:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/images/image.gif" Text="Menu Item AAA" />
    ...
```

You can set this in the markup code (as shown above) or in the designer, by right-clicking the menu and selecting "Edit Menu Items..."

Comment: ImageUrl docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.imageurl.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I tried using that property as it made sense to me, but image isnt showing up:

[code]
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Height="30px" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="MenuItem"
                BackColor="#ECE9D8" ForeColor="#333333">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Administration/Default.aspx" Text="Forside" 
                        Value="Forside" ImageUrl="~/Administration/Gfx/house.png">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
[/code]

Could there be anything im missing?

Comment: UPDATE: Made a new menu from scratch, image showing up ???? what is blocking the image in my existing code? Any know of anything that could do this?